# php preg_replace regex lookahead

Tags: regex, preg-replace, ampersand, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

Iam trying to replace Ampersands on my html sidewide using preg_replace, but the issue is that it breaks inline javascript && or javascript url like ?page=test&id=1

Now i have this code, which works

```
$amp_replace = array();
$amp_replace[0] = '/(?<=\s)&(?!&)(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/';
$amp_replace[1] = '/(?<!&)&(?=\s)/';
$skin = preg_replace($amp_replace, '&amp;', $skin);
```

Replaces ampersands when space on left or right. dont replace when 2 ampersand in a row ( for javascript ) or when following by html entity.

But i find it rather unneeded logic here. It also dont replace ampersands if its like test&test.

As iam no regex expert, this took me allready quite a while, so i thought i seek help here once again.

Wouldnt it be better to simply replace all ampersands if not within javascript script tags? I tried that allready but no real success

Does anyone know how i could archive that?
Thank you

Comment: How did these `&` get there in the first place? Shouldn't you rather be fixing that problem?

Comment: User submitted content. I know i could fix it by writing in each of my php files to fix ampersand outputs. But in this special case i dont need that. As my pp coding gets big enough i rather want to have one global statement for this. Look through all of my html and replace if not within script tags

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to convert '&' in *content* and avoid tags (ie: attribute values)
and avoid script blocks, something like below will work for most occurances.
However, it should be noted that attribute values should be converted as well.
And doing that requires a lot more work.

Working sample http://www.ideone.com/9MhCq

```
<?php

$html=<<<EOD
 <some &ta&g> S&P &&more; and &some; <more> &notme;
  && &#209; &#xa92F;
 <script flavor?>
   val && this & this 
 </script>
 &
EOD;

$rxent = '(?:&(?:[A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*|\#(?:[0-9]+|x[0-9a-fA-F]+));)';

$rxtag =
'<
 (?:
     \?php\s+.*?\?
  |  (?:
       (?:
           (?:script|style)\s*
         | (?:script|style)\s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+\s*
       )> .*? </(?:script|style)\s*
     )
  |  (?:
         /?[A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*\s*/?
       |  [A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*\s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+\s*/?
       | !(?:DOCTYPE.*?|--.*?--)
     )
 )
 >
';

$rxmain = "~(?xs:((?:$rxtag)+) | ((?!$rxent)&))~";


print "$html\n\n";

$html = preg_replace_callback($rxmain, 'fixamp_cb', $html);

print "$html\n";

function fixamp_cb( $matches ) {
    # Return tags and script blocks unchanged.
    if (isset($matches[1]) && $matches[1])
       return $matches[1];
    return '&amp;';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not something simple like:

`$html = preg_replace('/([^&])&([^&])/', '$1&amp;$2', $html);`

If you want to avoid replacing all ampersands inside Javascript, add lookahead/behind for script tags, or first split the document on script tags, and only run the replace on the non-script parts.

```
$html = preg_split('/<\/?script>/', $html);
foreach ($html as $k => $v) {
  if ($piece[0] == "<") {
    $html[$k] = preg_replace('/([^&])&([^&])/', '$1&amp;$2', $v);
  } else {
    $html[$k] = "<script>" . $html[$k] . "</script>";
}
```

This will need some modification if your script tags have attributes.

If you're sanitizing user content, then you might be better using the tools that are already available. See [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Comment: The $skin var is my parsed html, so i look through my hole html, this will not work in my case unfortunatly. as my above works but i want it simpliere, like replace all & if not within script tags. I know i could simply do a replace in each of my functions, but i rather would only write this once

Comment: Also tried it with the script tags, but it looks like i never get it right, either error or it dont replace